# Why clearInterval doesn't work if the setInterval was inside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function consoleTest() {
    setInterval(function(){
     console.log('Hello World');
    }, 1000);
}

$('#button').on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(consoleTest);
});

consoleTest();
```

I created a simple app when I click the button it will stop/pause the interval. I know how to make it work I just need to declare a variable outside the function and contain there the setInterval, now I am just confused why clearInterval won't work if I call it via a function, somebody please explain it to me.

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct usage of `setInterval` and `cleaInterval`.
`setInterval` returnes a value which you need to keep in a variable scoped for both function. When you want to clear the interval, use `clearInterval` and pass it the variable as a parameter:

```
var interval;

function consoleTest() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Hello World');
    }, 1000);
}

$('#button').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});

consoleTest();
```

For further reading: [clearInterval](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjazc6698jSAhWG1RoKHXsnCh4QFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_clearinterval.asp&usg=AFQjCNF5eXwLMatq9WhSrIXd736olamy2g&sig2=ho2-5EIw16bu9pa90FFlWQ) and [setInterval](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh5aCH-MjSAhVC7RQKHTGmCFkQFggYMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fmet_win_setinterval.asp&usg=AFQjCNGeKpvctZ0QksL4ryyHO0FVnU6BXw&sig2=sokPTCsVdZiDkNgew8e_ig).

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan, I added explenations. If it's not too much trouble, I'd appreicate clearing the comments section.

Comment: Thanks Koby, it make sense to me now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding !

Answer (score 2):

There's two issues here. Firstly you don't set the returned timer id from `setInterval()` anywhere. `consoleTest` is the function that wraps the timer, not a reference to the timer, which is what should be given to `clearInterval()`. Secondly, you need that timer reference to be in scope of both functions. With that in mind, try this:

```
function consoleTest() {
  return setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Hello World');
  }, 1000);
}

$('#button').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(interval);
});

var interval = consoleTest();
```

Comment: Wow! another great explanation, thanks Rory.